# Explicitly adding req and res to domain don't propagate error to express middleware

Tags: node.js, express

I'm playing around with domains and clusters in node with express and got into this circumstance. I have a cluster that spawns a worker per core, for each worker i create a express-server that uses a domain-per-request strategy to handle errors.

The solution given below is working fine as is but when explicitly adding the request and response objects to the domain the error middleware stops being called. I have no idea why this behaviour is introduced.

Questions:

1. Why is happening?
2. Am I using domains in the correct way?
3. Can i access the current domain in a worker through "process.domain"
   or do I need to do something different?

Thanks in advance!

My app.js:

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , domain = require('domain')
  , cluster = require('cluster')
  , http = require('http')
  , numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {

  // fork workers
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  // when a worker dies create a new one
  cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
    cluster.fork();
  });

} else {

  var app = express();

  //domains
  app.use(function domainMiddleware(req, res, next) {

    var reqDomain = domain.create();

    res.on('close', function () {
      reqDomain.dispose();
    });

    res.on('finish', function () {
      reqDomain.dispose();
    });

    reqDomain.on('error', function (err) {
      reqDomain.dispose();
      // delegate to express error-middleware
      next(err);
    });

    // Adding the request and response objects to the domain
    // makes the express error-middleware to not being called.
    // reqDomain.add(req);
    // reqDomain.add(res);

    reqDomain.run(next);
  });

  // all environments
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  //app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

  // for testing which cluster that serves the request
  app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.json(200, { id: cluster.worker.id });
  });
  app.get('/error', function(req, res, next) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    // intentionally force an error
    fs.readFile('', process.domain.intercept(function(data) { 
      // when using intercept we dont need this line anymore
      //if (err) throw err;
      res.send(data);
    }));
  });

  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log('ERROR MIDDLEWARE', err);
    res.writeHeader(500, {'Content-Type' : "text/html"});
    res.write("<h1>" + err.name + "</h1>");
    res.end("<p>" + err.message + "</p>");
  });

  http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the call to `reqDomain.dispose()`. From the [`dispose` documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html#domain_domain_dispose):

> The dispose method destroys a domain, and makes a best effort attempt to clean up any and all IO that is associated with the domain. Streams are aborted, ended, closed, and/or destroyed. Timers are cleared. Explicitly bound callbacks are no longer called. Any error events that are raised as a result of this are ignored.

Once `req` and `res` are added to the domain, disposing the domain [ends/closes/destroys them](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/9c7078cea2b719defbb6519d10a14ab15e733822/lib/domain.js#L221-227). You can test this by explicitly sending some output to `res` inside the `reqDomain.on('error')` callback, but before disposing the domain.

Simply moving the call to `next` up a line seems to fix the problem:

```
reqDomain.on('error', function (err) {
  next(err);
  reqDomain.dispose();
});
```

---

As for `process.domain`, I've not seen this before and was really surprised that it worked. I looked into the source code and [found the following](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/9c7078cea2b719defbb6519d10a14ab15e733822/lib/domain.js#L60-67):

```
Domain.prototype.enter = function() {
  if (this._disposed) return;

  // note that this might be a no-op, but we still need
  // to push it onto the stack so that we can pop it later.
  exports.active = process.domain = this;
  stack.push(this);
};
```

So, it appears that `process.domain` is always the "latest" domain. Personally, I would probably attach the domain to the `req` object or something, so that you can be more explicit about which domain should be handling the error (although in practice it may be that `process.domain` is always the domain you're looking for).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Your correct with moving the call "next(err)" up a line will fix this issue, though the req and res object could be disposed before some async-operation fires in the next middleware. I'm  fiddling around with a solution to dispose the domain at a error-middleware placed in the end of all middlewares but I am getting some strange results.

Apparently when your adding the req and res objects to the domain they will get the domain associated with them i.e. "req.domain" property will be set.

Comment: Ah, good call--I didn't consider that. And you're right--check out [this code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/9c7078cea2b719defbb6519d10a14ab15e733822/lib/domain.js#L83-112). I imagine that, overall, the domain code would be good to go over (and it's not too long, although some pieces of the picture are [in other files](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/9c7078cea2b719defbb6519d10a14ab15e733822/lib/timers.js#L209)).